# My WindowsFormsApplication going behind of all application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, formborderstyle

I developed a WindowsFormsApplication having a Form of Border Style as "FixedToolWindow", now the problem is while I am going to minimize any other opened application then my application going behind of all the application opened already. I am not getting where the problem is exactly. So can anybody help me to find out where the problem and how to short out it ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is called **Z order**, which is the internal top-to-bottom ordering of the windows that appear on the screen maintained by Windows.

When you click on that *other* application to minimize it, it becomes the "active" application and its window is moved to the foreground. That pushes your application (which used to be the foreground window) into the background, behind the other application. That causes its window to be hidden or obscured behind the window of the other application. Clicking on your application's window will bring it to the foreground again, causing it to cover up any windows that lie behind it.

But in answer to your real question, no, you should not have specified "FixedToolWindow" for the `BorderStyle` of your application's *main* window. Windows with that border style do not appear in the taskbar and are not treated as the main window of an application. That style is intended for *tool* windows, such as floating palettes, displayed in addition to an application's main window.

Comment: @Sharp: Change your form's `BorderStyle` property to [something else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx). Either "Fixed Single", "Fixed 3D", "Fixed Dialog", or "Sizable". That's still not going to change how Z ordering works. You can't get around that. Windows has had overlapping windows since version 2.0, and there's no going back now.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the real Scenario but any how I have to use the main window as "FixedToolWindow" because I don't have any other choice.

Comment: @Sharp: Why do you not have any choice? What does your application do, and why does the main window need to be a Tool Window? Perhaps if you told us what you were trying to accomplish, we could suggest something else. All that "FixedToolWindow" does for you is give your form a small title bar (to indicate that it's a tool window, not a main window), prevent it from appearing in the taskbar, and prevent it from showing up in the Alt+Tab application switcher. It doesn't sound like you want *either* of those things.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct and thanks for your suggestion. Now I am using "FixedSingle" border style for my application.

Answer (score 2):

If your form is intended to be a **tool window** then perhaps you would like it to appear above all other forms when shown.

Therefore, set it's **TopMost** property to True.

Otherwise, I agree with [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray), no main form should have a *FixedToolWindow* border style.

Comment: But please don't set your application's main window to be `TopMost`. That's just a huge pain in the rear for your users, who will then be forced to *close* your application when they want to do something else, lest it covers up everything else on their screen.

Comment: Agreed, definitely not a good idea for a main form, unless that is the intention.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you guys for kind help